# Using ShowDialog() to open form with a DataGridView in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

So, I have an application with two forms and one of the main one and the other one is called when I press **F1** and it goes to another form with a `DataGridView`. It will open the second form as a new form, but I want it to be opened with `Form2.ShowDialog();` instead `Form2.Show();`.

This press **F1** event is being used on the `TextBox` from the main form and after inserting something into that `TextBox` it will search in my database the records depending on what was written in the `TextBox`.

It works if I use `Form2.Show();`, but if I change to `Form2.ShowDialog();` it won't process data and the `DataGridView` will be empty without displaying any records.

This is what I got in the main for:

```
private void txtCarga_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F1)
    {
        frmPesquisa frmP = new frmPesquisa(this);
        frmP.Show();

        con = new SqlConnection(cs.DBConnP);
        con.Open();

        //The rest of the code is calling the query
}
```

Then, in the second form I have this:

```
private frmPrincipal frm;

public frmPesquisa(frmPrincipal frm)
            : this()
{
    this.frm = frm;
}
```

What can I do to display the `DataGridView` in the second form using `Form2.ShowDialog();`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`ShowDialog`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk(v=vs.110).aspx) shows the window modally, so it's a blocking call while the child form is open:

> You can use this method to display a modal dialog box in your application. When this method is called, the code following it is not executed until after the dialog box is closed.

This means you're not populating the DataGridView until **after the form has been closed**.

You need to populate the DataGridView and any other controls on Form2 *before* calling ShowDialog.